# Where can I buy the Invisibility spell book?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can anyone tell me where to buy the invisibility spell book? I've been to several people, but can't seem to find the right one.

Comment: How high is your illusion skill level? Invisibility is an expert level spell (~75 skill) and if your skill is low, the higher level stuff won't even show up on the vendors to begin with.

Comment: Its extremely low. I mostly follow the destructive spells. So that's most likely why I haven't seen it. But I've had spells become available and I didn't even have enough mana to cast them, but that goes back to your skill level I guess...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only buy it from the [illusion trainer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Drevis_Neloren) in the College of Winterhold, but he won't sell it until your illusion is of sufficient expertise (i.e. expert level).

Comment: Thanks! I've never played the series before so that makes sense that there are more available for the school you excel in.

Answer (score 9):

From what I've experienced, the spell merchants in The College of Winterhold will actually begin selling the spells to you 10 levels before you can buy the perk associated with that particular proficiency level. I saw this when I was training Alteration: Tolfdir sold me Telekinesis when I only had an alteration skill of 40. I also had a similar experience with my Conjuration tomes. So you should be able to purchase that tome once your Illusion reaches 65 and then only from the Illusion trainer at the college.

I don't see why this wouldn't work with other schools of magic as well but haven't had a chance to test it myself yet. If anyone else could confirm, it would be nice.

Comment: This is why anyone can buy any novice or apprentice spell from any court mage in Skyrim, even if you skill in that school is only 15(10 below what's needed to get the cost reducing perk for apprentice). You most certainly can buy adept spells at 40 skill and expert spells at 65 skill. You are supposed to be able to start the quest for master spells in a school when you hit 90 skill, which is true in most cases. There are 1 or 2 schools that are bugged, so you have to have 100 skill before you are allowed to start the related quest.